# Memory issues with String.split()

Tags: java, string, memory

My programs currently has memory problems, and upon checking the app, we've discovered that the `String.split()` method uses lots of memory. I've tried using a `StreamTokenizer`, but it seems this makes things even more complex.

Is there a better way to split long `Strings` into small `Strings` that uses less memory than the `String.split()` method?

Comment: How many times do you split this string really? Can you show some code?

Comment: Did you try StringTokenizer in java? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: hey i will try StringTokenizer, thanks.

Comment: split creates a lot of garbage but doesn't use very much memory. I suspect your memory problem is elsewhere. What do you see when you use a memory profiler?

Comment: As i remembered,  i use the String[] strs to refer to the returned value from String.split. and then put each of the String of strs into HashMap as the key. that`s may be the cause of the memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that any realistic use of split would "consume lots of memory". Your input would have to be huge (many, many megabytes) and your result split into *many millions* of parts for it to even be noticed.

Here's some code that creates a random string of approximately 1.8 million characters and splits it into over 1 million Strings and outputs the memory used and time taken.

As you can see, it ain't much: 61Mb consumed in just 350ms.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
        sb.append(Math.random());
    }
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String string = sb.toString();
    sb = null;
    System.gc();
    long startFreeMem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    String[] strings = string.split("(?=[0-5])");
    long endFreeMem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    long execution = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;

    System.out.println("input length = " + string.length() + "\nnumber of strings after split = " + strings.length + "\nmemory consumed due to split = "
            + (startFreeMem - endFreeMem) + "\nexecution time = " + execution + "ms");
}
```

Output (run on fairly typical windows box):

```
input length = 1827035
number of strings after split = 1072788
memory consumed due to split = 71740240
execution time = 351ms
```

Interestingly, *without* `System.gc()` the memory used was about 1/3:

```
memory consumed due to split = 29582328
```

Comment: I would use `-XX:-UseTLAB` for more accurate memory usage and move the `sb.toString()` to before your `start` Splitting on 60% of characters is a little crazy. How about `[0-1]`?

Comment: Pet hate: Don't use StringBuffer is you can use StringBuilder. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Crap! I meant to use `StringBuilder`. And I moved the `toString()`. Bit less memory used by `split()`. Splitting on so much because I wanted to create a crazy number of String objects to prove `split()` is not the villain.

Comment: Did you try turning off the TLAB? (Just curious) I would also try `System.gc()` before getting the memory used to ignore temporary objects (OP appears to be concerned about retained objects)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Turning off TLAB reduced memory used to about 25Mb, however running `gc()` made memory used leap to 71Mb!

Comment: Try doing the split twice to see if it scales.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I had to use Xms=Xmx to stop it grabbing more and throwing off the memory measurements, but split #2 used just 9Mb

Comment: I suspect that 9 MB is more accurate. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Split does not create brand new strings, it uses `substring` internally which creates a new `String` object that points to the right substring of the original string, without copying the underlying `char[]`.

So apart from the (slight) overhead of object creation, it should not have a huge impact from a memory perspective.

ps: `StringTokenizer` uses the same technique so it would probably yield the same results as split.

**EDIT**

To see that it is the case, you can use the sample code below. It splits `abc,def` into `abc` and `def` then prints the underlying `char[]` of the original string and of the split strings - the output shows that they are all the same.

Output:

```
Reference: [C@3590ed52  Content: [a, b, c, ,, d, e, f]
Reference: [C@3590ed52  Content: [a, b, c, ,, d, e, f]
Reference: [C@3590ed52  Content: [a, b, c, ,, d, e, f]
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    String s = "abc,def";
    String[] ss = s.split(",");
    Field f = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println("Reference: " + f.get(s) + "\tContent: " + Arrays.toString((char[])f.get(s)));
    System.out.println("Reference: " + f.get(ss[0]) + "\tContent: " + Arrays.toString((char[])f.get(ss[0])));
    System.out.println("Reference: " + f.get(ss[1]) + "\tContent: " + Arrays.toString((char[])f.get(ss[1])));
}
```

Comment: in the substring method, it will finally create a new String with the new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value), and when new String(xxx) was called, the jvm`ll make a copy of char[] value in the cache pool once it`s not existed , is that correct ?

Comment: no the new string will use the same `char[]` as the original one. Now if you split to only keep a small portion of the original string, you will actually carry the whole string around as you keep a reference to its `char[]` in each of the substrings.

Comment: Sorry, i just read the source code, and i was wrong. it does use the copy to improve the memory performance

Answer (score 0):

split maybe aspect memory if you just want to use one or few arrays of the long string.
the long string will always in memory.
like

```
private static List<String> headlist = new ArrayList<String>();

String longstring = ".....";
headlist.add(longstring.split(" ")[0]);
```

than the longstring will always in memory. JVM cannot gc it.

in this situation, I think maybe you can try

```
private static List<String> headlist = new ArrayList<String>();

String longstring = ".....";
headlist.add(new String(longstring.split(" ")[0]));
```

as following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class SplitTest {
    static Random rand = new Random();
    static List<String> head = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            String a = constructLongString();
            head.add(a.split(" ")[0]); //1
            //head.add(new String(a.split(" ")[0])); //2
            if (i % 1000 == 0)
                System.out.println("" + i);
            System.gc();
        }
    }

    private static String constructLongString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sb.append(rand.nextInt(10));
        }
        sb.append(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
            sb.append(rand.nextInt(10));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

if you running with -Xmx60M, it will outofmemory about 6000+
and if you using code line 2, comment the line 1, then it running long time more bigger than 6000

Comment: hi, good point and thanks. I will check the code to see whether the mistake exists

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of stream reader and not to abuse the memory with big data string. 
here some example :

```
 public static void readString(String str) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        char[] buf = new char[2048];
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");

        while (true) {
            int n = r.read(buf);
            if (n < 0)
                break;

            /*
             StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
             s.append(buf, 0, n);
             ... now you can parse the StringBuilder ...  
            */
        }
    }
```